# Validate Weblogic Server Config.xml file with the correspondig schema

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, xml-validation, application-server

I have developed a tool to generate domain config files (config.xml and others) based on the set of velocity templates.
I now want to do a schema validation for this generated config.xml file.
Could you please suggest is there an api provided by weblogic, or what approach is better.
I tried with validating with the oracle provided schema (http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain/1.0/domain.xsd), but i am getting error where one of the data type defined in the schema is not getting resolved.

Thanks.

Comment: any progress in this vedant ?